# bash script - getting highest file name number from folder

Tags: linux, scripting

I tries a lot of whys to solve the following problem without a solution :(

I have a folder which contains files with the following name pattern:

```
 number_name.txt
```

for example:

```
0_test.txt
17_test.txt
39_test.txt
99_test.txt
101_test.txt
17_test.txt
```

I need to get the file name which contain the max prefix number.

(when I compare the strings, I'm getting that "99_test.txt" is the highest which is not true....)

Thanks

Comment: great question bro

Answer (score 5):

Using version sort:

```
find -name '*.txt' | sort -V | tail -1
```

Comment: thats number 1 after tail btw